# Corda - ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com connection refused

Tags: corda

I've just built a new OS install for my home PC, installed IntelliJ and cloned a project that requires Corda. *(In order to explain the issue here, I'm using the corda/samples repository).*

Upon importing the gradle project I get the following error:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'cordapp-example'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve net.corda.plugins:cordapp:4.0.45.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve net.corda.plugins:cordapp:4.0.45.
         > Could not get resource 'https://ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com/artifactory/corda-releases/net/corda/plugins/cordapp/4.0.45/cordapp-4.0.45.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com/artifactory/corda-releases/net/corda/plugins/cordapp/4.0.45/cordapp-4.0.45.pom'.
               > Connect to ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com:443 [ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com/13.93.114.78] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
   > Could not resolve net.corda.plugins:cordformation:4.0.45.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve net.corda.plugins:cordformation:4.0.45.
         > Could not get resource 'https://ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com/artifactory/corda-releases/net/corda/plugins/cordformation/4.0.45/cordformation-4.0.45.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com/artifactory/corda-releases/net/corda/plugins/cordformation/4.0.45/cordformation-4.0.45.pom'.
               > Connect to ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com:443 [ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com/13.93.114.78] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
   > Could not resolve net.corda.plugins:quasar-utils:4.0.45.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve net.corda.plugins:quasar-utils:4.0.45.
         > Could not get resource 'https://ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com/artifactory/corda-releases/net/corda/plugins/quasar-utils/4.0.45/quasar-utils-4.0.45.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com/artifactory/corda-releases/net/corda/plugins/quasar-utils/4.0.45/quasar-utils-4.0.45.pom'.
               > Connect to ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com:443 [ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com/13.93.114.78] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

In short...

> Connect to ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com:443 [ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com/13.93.114.78] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)

I tried the same thing on my work PC, which has been running IntelliJ and Corda for some time now, and I didn't get the same problem, so my first assumption was that it's a problem with my home PC, though I wasn't entirely convinced, so on my work machine I **forcibly** cleared out all of the gradle caches *(Invalidate caches and restart from IntelliJ won't help you here).*

```
rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/
```

Now, I get the same problem on my work PC as well, which suggests to me that gradle won't bother to fetch the dependencies if they're already locally cached, which I would expect.

Any ideas on how to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems on this occasion, R3's DevOps were performing some maintenance on the artifactory servers. It's unlikely that this issue will recur very often, but I'll keep it open just in case anyone else happens to run into this issue.

P.S. I've also upgraded my gradle dependency to now use the following:

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://software.r3.com/artifactory/corda' }
    ...
}
```